# Binary function equivalence - demethodize

Tags: javascript

I was watching a Pluralsight video from Douglas Crockford: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/javascript-good-parts

In this video he goes through a number of interesting exercises to demonstrate some javascript principals.
When he gets to the 'demethodize' function you basically have the following code sample:

```
function add(x,y){
  return x + y;
}
//add(1,2) => 3

function methodize(fn){
  return function(x){
    return fn(this, x);
  };
};
Number.prototype.Add = methodize(add);
//(1).Add(2) => 3

function demethodize (fn){
  return function(x,y){ 
    return fn.call(x,y); 
  };
}
var newAdd = demethodize(Number.prototype.Add);
// newAdd(1,2) => 3
```

Note that this 'demethodize' function is for binary functions only.

My question is that, according to my understanding, the following should result in an equivalent 'demethodise' functions:

```
function demethodize (fn){
  return fn.call;
}
```

or

```
var demethodize = Number.prototype.Add.call;
```

But these functions do not work (given the same binary function requirement)! 
Why is this?

Please help me fill the gap in my understanding.
I had thought that if I had a binary function whose implementation contained another binary function call with the same arguments passed to the inner function, then using the inner function call directly would be equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your `demethodize` function is the `Function.prototype.call` function - not bound to your `fn`, i.e. with no [`this` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (which it had if it was called as `fn.call(…)`). You can however use the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to fix that:

```
function demethodize(fn) {
  return Function.prototype.call.bind(fn);
}
// or long:
function demethodize(fn) {
  return function(context/*, args... */) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return fn.apply(context, args);
    // equivalent (for binary functions) to
    return fn.call(context, args[0]);
    //       ^^^^^^ is a method invocation here
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `call` doesn't know on which function it is supposed to be called. Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for how `this` works.

It's the same as

```
var foo = {bar: function() { console.log(this); }};
foo.bar(); // logs foo
var bar = foo.bar;
bar(); // logs window
```

You changed the way how `.call` is executed and with that you changed what `this` refers to.